# Constraint for few values or how can I find existing such (the same two columns) data

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a table:

Table:

```
A B C
1 x q
2 y w
3 y e
4 z r
5 z t
6 z r
```

*SQL magic*

And I want to check something, like  unique constraint for two same values, in columns B and C. To select B and C (id=4 and id=6) and output something like *combination z + r are duplicate* logic.

I mean this:

Result:

```
z r
```

Is here I need to use something like double group by + having ?
Hove then I can create the constraint to prevent the entry of such data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select b, c
from your_table
group by b, c
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfect for me, even with three items - where one of them is not null (additional predicate condition)

Answer (score 0):

To check your data

```
select a.B, a.C from mytable a join mytable b
on a.B=b.B and a.C=b.C 
where a.A<>b.A
```

Then you can add a unicity constraint on B and C