# Oracle constraint / unique index: check if the query has no result - then you can insert the line

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

I did something similar in the past for the purpose of limiting the range of cells:

```
ALTER TABLE "CES"."NS_CES" ADD CONSTRAINT "CHECK_OVER_DIAPAZON" CHECK (
        (ID_NS_WORK != 1835 AND ID_NS_WORK != 1833) OR
        (ID_NS_WORK = 1835 and PNS BETWEEN 0 AND 100 and QNS BETWEEN -200 AND 10) OR
        (ID_NS_WORK = 1833 and PNS BETWEEN 0 AND 100 and QNS BETWEEN -200 AND 10)
    );
```

But now I've got different task: add constraint, which will check the result of the query does not return any value.

This is my select, which must return no value, and which I want to create as check constraint for the table Training_rule:

```
select type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code
from training_rule
where after_rule is null and after_group is null
group by type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code
having count(*) > 1;
```

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "CES"."TRAINING_RULE" ADD CONSTRAINT "CHEK_SELECT_HAS_NO_RESULT" CHECK (
    ^HAS NO RESULT^:
    [
    select type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code
        from training_rule
        where after_rule is null and after_group is null
        group by type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code
        having count(*) > 1;
    ]
)
```

Thanks

### Edit 1

It works, thanks to *Gordon Linoff*

```
create unique index idx_trainingrule_4 on TRAINING_RULE (
         type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code,
         (case when after_rule is null and after_group is null then null
               else name
          end)
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with a conditional unique index.  This assumes that you have a unique id column in the table (`trainingrule_id`) that is never negative:

```
create unique index idx_trainingrule_4 on (
         type, training_list_id, element_id, request_code,
         (case when after_rule is null and after_group is null then -1
               else trainingrule_id
          end)
        );
```

Comment: Wow, interesting construction. But I think now next thing: if is it taken into account group by + having construction from my main select statement( for this purpose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32320217/constraint-for-few-values-or-how-can-i-find-existing-suchthe-same-two-cloumns )

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it like that. The [ADD CHECK CONSTRAINT](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/check.php):

> - A check constraint can NOT be defined on a SQL View.
> - The check constraint defined on a table must refer to only columns in    that table. It can not refer to columns in other tables.
> - A check constraint can NOT include a SQL Subquery.
> - A check constraint can be defined in either a SQL CREATE TABLE    statement or a SQL ALTER TABLE statement.

The reason why it was working previously was because you were applying the constraint on a column value which is syntactically correct. But the latter is not the correct syntax and is not allowed.